# Displaying a Message after Exporting data in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I have a Web page in which datas will be Exported on button click.

I need to display a Message as "Exported Successfully" once the Export is Completed.

But after Exporting the Message is not displaying...

My Code:

```
protected void btnGenReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
      System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
      hw.WriteLine("Sample Text");
      Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
      Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"Sample.xls\"");
      Response.Write(tw);
      Response.End();
      lblMessage.Text = "Exported Successfully";
}
```

How should I display the message.....

Comment: Put `Response.End();` at the end

Comment: I tried... But no use.... The Msg is not displaying

Answer (score 0):

> Remove Response.End() and let the response end naturally within the
>   ASP.NET ecosystem.
>
> If that does not work, I would recommend putting the button in a
>   separate  and post the required data to a separate HTTP handler.
>   Setup the HTTP handler to export the XML instead of a web page.

[Post Back does not work after writing files to response in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336883/post-back-does-not-work-after-writing-files-to-response-in-asp-net)